# Python - Raising custom exception

Tags: python, exception

What will be the proper way to raise an exception and let the user know that it was raised from my_module, even if its a common python exception, like a ValueError:

```
#my_module.exceptions.py
    class MyModuleError(Exception):
        pass

#my_module.do_something.py
    def do_something(*args):
        try:
           some logic here
        except Exception as e: 
           # i dont know in advance what kinds of exceptions
           # this code might throw 
           raise MyModuleError('An error ocurred %s' % (repr(e))
```

I would like the user to know that the exception was trown inside of my module, even tho it was a general python Exception.

**Edit1:** sorry, i should´ve explained better:
Even tho i dont know what kind of exceptions the code above might throw, i´d like the user to know that it was an error originated from my_module.
Is this even best practice? 
How should i handle unexpected exceptions inside custom modules?

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions

Comment: This is already accomplished by the traceback, which shows the originating exception (and its module).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
#...

raise ValueError('This exception was raised from myModule')

#....
```